# Как в функции применить в запросе второй параметр если первый не задан?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть таблицы `table1`, `table2:`

```
| ID  | amount |                | ID  | Code   |
+-----+--------+                +-----+--------+
| 1   |  302   |                | 1   | N418   |
| 41  |  54    |                | 41  | S479   |
| 1   |  344   |
```

Функция должна работать так:

Если задали `id`, то ищем по `id`, если не задано `id`, то по коду должны возвращать сумму.

Код:

```
create or replace function GetSum(p_id  in number,
                                  p_Cod in varchar2 default null)
  return number as
  nTotal number;
  vCod   varchar2;
begin
  select sum(t1.amount), t2.code
    into nTotal, vCod
    from table1 t1, table2 t2
   where t1.id = t2.id
     and t1.id = p_id
        
return nTotal;
end GetSum;
```

Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь, задав один из двух параметров, получил сумму?

Comment: Не задано - это NULL?

Comment: @Akina, да, ну чтобы user передал какой либо параметр из этих двух и возвращалась сумма

Comment: `((p_id is null AND t2.code=p_Cod) OR t1.id=p_id)`

Comment: @Mike, долго работает

Comment: значит надо смотреть план выполнения и разбираться почему именно работает долго. может индекса какого не хватает, может индекс какой построить надо. Или например получать id по коду заранее и в запрос всегда передавать id

Comment: Используйте `IF p_id IS NULL THEN (один запрос) ELSE (второй запрос)`. Опять же непонятно - вроде как `p_id` у тебя обязательный параметр, и DEFAULT у него нет - как его могут "не задать"?

Comment: @akina, можно нулл передать

Comment: Можно. Однако "задать NULL" и "не задать" - это разные вещи, во втором случае параметр должен быть optional и в принципе опущен при вызове (и при этом он обязан иметь значение по умолчанию).

Answer (score 2):

Такой вариант:

```
create or replace function GetSum (id number, code varchar2 := null) return number as
    total number;
begin
    select sum (t1.amount) into total
    from t1
    where t1.id in (
        select t2.id from t2 where t2.id = GetSum.id 
        union all 
        select t2.id from t2 where not exists (
            select 1 from t2 where id = GetSum.id)
        and t2.code = GetSum.code 
    );
    return nvl (total, 0);
end GetSum;
```

С правильными индексами будет работать быстро:

```
t1.id FK (t2.id); t2.id PK; t2.code unique not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Задать всем атрибутам которые не обязательны значение по умолчанию, а дальше через if или dynamic SQL

пример с ифами

```
create or replace function GetSum(p_id  in number:= Null, 
                                  p_Cod in varchar2 default null)
  return number as
  nTotal number;
  vCod   varchar2;
begin
 if p_id is not Null and  p_Cod is not Null then
          --ваш запрос если p_id и p_Cod задан
          null;
 elsif p_id is Null and  p_Cod is not Null then
          --ваш запрос если задан только p_Cod
          null;
 elsif p_id is not Null and  p_Cod is Null then
          --ваш запрос если задан только p_id
          null;
 else 
          --если ничего не задано, вернуть что то или вызвать исключение
          null;
end if;

return nTotal;
end GetSum;
```